# How to check permanently textbox value change

Tags: javascript

I need some help regarding monitoring textbox value change.

Here's the scenario: I have a form that has some textbox that are filled out by javascript calendar. As soon as I choose the date calendar populates textbox with date. However, textbox never gets the focus. Now, i need to check the value that is placed in textbox as soon textbox gets the info from calendar. Basically the reason is that I need to compare dates and verify that date 2 is not lower than date 1.

`OnChange`, `OnBlur`, `OnKeyup` events do not work for what I'm trying to do. I mean, they work if I use it but is not what I need.

I have tried some code but for some reason event never fires up or never detects the change.

Here's some example of what I'm trying to do:

```
$('#date2').bind('input', function() {
    /* This will be fired every time, when textbox's value changes. */
} );
```

And

```
jQuery('#date2').on('input', function() {
    // do your stuff
});
```

Is there any way to do that? Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: maybe on('change',function(){}) -->https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: You probably have an event on the calendar widget you're using for when a date is selected. Without know what that widget is, I can't give you any answer.

Comment: Agree with Mike, without knowing what calendar widget you are using, we can't answer.  For example, if you are using the Ajax Control Toolkit's calendar extender, that will fire the change event on the textbox the date is going into.  The change event is what you want to use, but just about any other widget, when you programmatically change the text in a textbox, the change event is not fired.  We need more detail.

Comment: Thanks for yout prompt response. Here's the calendar I'm using: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/DateTimePicker-control-for-ASPNet-TextBox-Example.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what your saying, I'll try and push you in the right direction. You desire to read information from a textbox when a calendar puts information into it?

A simple jquery command you can use to give something automatic focus. Though only one thing can have focus at once so you can't set it to multiple items.

```
$(function() {
  $("#date2").focus();
});
```

You can also call en event when something receives focus. Such as inputting a string into a textbox. This can be used for multiple items.

```
$(selector).focus(function)
```

The *selector* being your element ID and the *function* being whatever you desire to happen.

See the link for more information.

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_focus.asp)

**Edit**

Isn't that what your field

```
displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')"
```

is for? The date should be placed there. Why can't you grab it from there or change it so it places it into your textbox?

Comment: I was not able to set focus to textbox when Calendar populates it.

Comment: Show me your script (note if you press 'space' four times it places the code in the grey box like above so it's easier for us to read!).

Comment: Unfortunately I have commented that line and date is still appearing in textbox with no focus. I did it for testing purposes so I can change settings but doesn't work. //displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support older browsers, you can use [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm trying to do:

As soon as calendar icon is clicked you can choose a date. After choosing a date you use this code to pass the date to textbox called 'Fecha Vencimiento'. Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%=txtFechaVencimiento.ClientID %>").dynDateTime({
                showsTime: false,
                //ifFormat: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M",
                //ifFormat: "%Y/%m/%d",
                ifFormat: "%d/%m/%Y",
                daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m, %Y",
                align: "BR",
                electric: false,
                singleClick: false,
                displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
                button: ".next()"
            });
            $("#txtFechaVencimiento").focus();
        });
    </script>
```

Focus is not working for that textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this part of the code is not needed at all. Se commented lines:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%=txtFechaVencimiento.ClientID %>").dynDateTime({
                //showsTime: false,
                //ifFormat: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M",
                //ifFormat: "%Y/%m/%d",
                //ifFormat: "%d/%m/%Y",
                //daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m, %Y",
                //align: "BR",
                //electric: false,
                //singleClick: false,
                //displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
                button: ".next()"
            });
        });
```

Last line button:"next()" is the one that calls the date and puts it into text box. This is the calendar I'm using: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/DateTimePicker-control-for-ASPNet-TextBox-Example.aspx